# How exactly a 'shutdown -h' “HALT” differ from “normal shutdown” in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, reboot

Suppose I have 20 process/deqamons running in my linux system, 
How different the HALT will have an effect on my process/deamons, 
when compared to a normal shutdown..,

*Note: 
I need to understand..one of my device proc fails to react for ioctl calls midst while using the shutdown -h command,
But works properly in case of shutdown -r reboot option..,

Answer (score 0):

shutdown schedules a time for the system to be powered down. It may be used to halt, power-off or reboot the machine.

```
shutdown -h
```

is equivalent to : `shutdown --poweroff` simply it means POWEROFF.

in the other hand

```
shutdown -H
```

or

```
shutdown --halt
```

instructs the hardware to stop all CPU functions, but leaves it powered on. You can use it to get the system to a state where you can perform low level maintenance.
Note that in some cases it completely shuts down the system. Below are examples of halt